# How to create and add 'buy now' button along with add to cart button on each product?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, javascript, addtocart

I am new to Magento, using Magento 1.9. with a custom theme. I successfully created buy now button on `addtocart.phtml` by the following codes

`<button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(", true, true) ?>`

---

But am confused in **where to paste below javascript on my `view.phtml`?** can anyone say exactly next to which function or step number, I should paste these scripts?

```
<script>
   jQuery.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:location,
     success:function(data){
       window.location.href = "http://www.your-site.com/checkout/onepage/";
     }
   });
</script>
```

I planned to have 2 buttons, without disturbing each other: When someone clicks

> Buy Now button which should redirect to `checkout/onepage`
>
> Add to cart button should do its default `checkout/cart`

Thanks in advance. Any suggestions are very welcome! :)

Comment: Use that script in addtocart.phtml itself

Comment: @ Meenakshi Sundaram : As you said,when buynow button is clicked its simply adding product to cart but not redirecting to `checkout/onepage`

Comment: Can you provide the link from where you found that script. It needs to intercept between your button click action to work properly,

Comment: Check your product is added in the cart. Then check your ajax response in browser console.

Comment: @Prateek I get those codes from `http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/` [link](http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/)

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR Products are getting added succesfully to cart but not redirecting to `checkout/onepage`                                                                                                                                                                                                   Am getting `SyntaxError: illegal character` on brower console,My test site is `www.indianskart`.com [link](http://indianskart.com/index.php/hp-deskjet-1510-multifunction-inkjet-printer.html)

Comment: You are seeing that error because in process of copy/paste, you forgot to remove those bloggy ”GET”, change them with your keyboard's default double quotes :) Also, add type attribute to your button element as button so that it doesn't automatically tries to submit the form for you.

Comment: @Prateek Thanks for helping,I tried as you said but still am not getting any changes in my site.Is thereany other possible ways to do it? I want to craete a **BUYNOW** button which should redirect to `checkout/onepage`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9 How to add buy now button in product page?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123072/magento-1-9-how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-product-page)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question since OP has a javascript code which do it's purpose and he is only confused with where should it has to be placed. The referenced question asks for a different thing. Please read descriptions before flag it as off-topic.

Comment: I´m not a programer but I run my shop with magento, I tried to use the last sugestion and works fine.
But add only 1 unit of the product.
How can I do to ad the quantities as the client needs? Today my original code is bellow. Thanks! ?> <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?> <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?> <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?> <div class="add-to-cart left-side"> <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?> <div class="qty-wrapper"> <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label> <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $t

Answer (score 4):

Kindly open app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Add below line into `<form>` Tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="buy_now" id="buy_now" value="" />
```

Put below button at anywhere where you want

```
<button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><i class="cart-icon-white m-r-sm v-middle"></i>Buy Now</button>
```

Now open app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

First of all move this file into the local folder and change the code as below instructions

Put below line in `_goBack()` function at very first

```
$buy_now = $this->getRequest()->getParam('buy_now');
```

FInd the line $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl); and replace this line as below code

```
if (!empty($buy_now)) {
    $this->_redirect('onepagecheckout'); // If you are using onepagecheckout or use this $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/')
}else{
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
}
```

Code Taken from this link http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-add-buynow-button-on-product.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution.

In your app\design\frontend\default[your theme]\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml   add the below code after add to cart button.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Check out') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/url') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?></span></span></button>
 <script>
 function setcheckoutLocation(location,chkout)
 {
  jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = chkout;
                }
             });
}
</script>
```