# How to add Buy now button at product single page in magento - 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, buy-now, customize

I have developed one [Website](https://depoto.com/) on magento-1.9 version. Everything is working fine. Now, i need to add Buy now button additionally beside to the add to cart button at [Single product page](https://www.depoto.com/deep-groove-ball-bearing-skf-6200-html.html).

Comment: i can see an add to cart already in product page?

Comment: edited, please check

Comment: what needs to be done if a customer clicks buy now?

Comment: What is the difference between  Buy now button and add to cart

Comment: If customer clicks on add to cart, that is redirects to cart page, when customer clicks on buy now, that should redirects to checkout page directly.

Comment: Check with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123072/magento-1-9-how-to-add-buy-now-button-in-product-page

Comment: You can also check with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/how-to-create-and-add-buy-now-button-along-with-add-to-cart-button-on-each-pro

Comment: i tried those but not succed

Answer (score 0):

Create a new module with a new ControllerAction just like CartController::addAction() and write a redirect to checkout onepage.

Make a request to that function with the button "Buy Now".

Answer (score 0):

I will give you 2 solutions:

Either

1: you create an observer `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event to redirect to checkout whene you add a product instead a cart.

or

2: you rewrite `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`in your local codepool and rewrite the function `protected function _goBack()` and change at the end `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');` to `$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');`

Comment: Can you tell me more clearly please
> in your local codepool  means ?

Comment: app/code/`local`<-this is a local code pool, So to change the native behavior of magento, you must rewrite the file to not change directly in the core, it is forbidden. you can find many tutorials to know how to rewrite a cartController

Comment: You mean, i need to create this CartController.php file in my local at the same path and need to edit that url right?

Comment: No, you rewrite it in your local but just not the same path, refere you to this exemple https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92172/how-to-override-the-controller-accountcontroller